# Testing Microsoft Bot Framework Async replies

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, botframework

I am testing my Bot using Mocha and Chai (BDD mode).

I want to listen from the event emitter to check which reply I've got and assert if it makes sense based on the text I had sent.

My tests usually follow this patten:

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
    bot = require('myModule').textBot;
    bot.removeAllListeners('reply');
    done();
});

describe('', function(){
    it('', function (done) {
        bot.on('reply', function (message) {
            assert.include(message.text.toLowerCase(), '');
            done();
        });
        bot.processMessage({text: 'message_that_will_trigger'});
    });
});
```

I have multiple describes and multiple its on my tests. Occasionally, a reply will be triggered on the wrong reply callback (even though I reset all callbacks on the beforeEach), so the tests will fail.

If I run only the specific test. They pass.

Is this the best way to test this? How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

If anyone else stumbles upon this. Make sure you assert something prior to your "done" call...

I had a test that was not asserting anything and apparently that screwed up other tests. After removing the test, everything ran smoothly.

Comment: Mocha does not care at all whether or not you assert something before calling `done`.